# jQuery plugin as directive and calling public method on plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bxslider

I successfully made a jQuery plugin into a directive.

```
app.directive('bxSlider', function($timeout)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $timeout(function(){element.bxSlider(scope.$eval(attrs.bxSlider))},1);
        }
    }
});
```

In my controller (through a click function), I'd like to call a method that is public on the plugin, but I am not sure how to do that. I tried setting the directive to a variable and calling it that way from my controller, but I get the error of ...has no method...

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not bind the click listener in the link function of your directive? It would be easier to help if you could specify the exact function you want to call as well as the button's position in the DOM.

Comment: @Jonathan Well, the jQuery plugin has a public function called `reloadSlider()` I want to call that function when I click a button. It's simply a `<button ng-click="changeItems()">Change Items</button>` and the `changeItems()` function is in my controller

Comment: create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net. Typically you would work within the API of the plugin but your plugin config options aren't present. You can also add methods within the link callback of your directive

Answer (score 0):

You could broadcast an event to trigger your plugin method.

```
app.directive('bxSlider', function($timeout)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var slider;
            $timeout(function() {
                slider = element.bxSlider(scope.$eval(attrs.bxSlider));
            }, 1);

            scope.$on('reload-slider', function() {
                slider.reloadSlider();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then in the controller function you use `$scope.$broadcast('reload-slider')`.